# Image in TableView not getting displayed and lazyloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an `image` and i want to display it as the default image in a `cell` of a `UITableViewController`. For some reason it is not getting displayed.

```
cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"R1.jpg"];
```

1.) What might be the problem here ?
2.) Sometimes downloading takes time, if so how do i implement lazyloading, so it'll download and display images simultaneously ?

Comment: Your code has no reference whatsoever that you're loading this picture from anywhere. If you have included your R1.jpg file in the Xcode project and your `cell.myImageView` imageView is visible and is displayed correctly - your image should be displayed inside it.

Comment: i have added the R1.jpg to the xcode project. Still its not getting displayed.

Comment: Have you added it to the Supporting Files folder in xcode project? It can't just be in any folder.

Comment: I added it now. but still it's not getting displayed.

Comment: (It doesn't need to be in the Supporting Files folder, just has to be somewhere in the project.)  Show some more code, such as  cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Use afnetworking uitools. It has lazy loading imageview and perfectly works with tableview. Also has placeholder image support and cache support too. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking

Edit: add your placeholder image to your apps source files.

> Good Answer Edit:

**There are several things to check why local image doesn't load:**

- Your image can be corrupted.
- You should add image to resources. Goto:  Target -> "Build Phases" -> "copy bundle Resources" is your image here too. If it is, remove and add again.
- Clean and build project.time to time xcode makes something like this.
- `UIImage *tempImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"R1.jpg"];` check this 'tempImage' is null or empty. That can help to solve where is your problem (loading resource or displaying on uitableview).
- Check tableview cellforRow method in case of your cell is null or your cell's referance is wrong.
- Check tableview cellforRow method cell.myImageView can be null. (that means your cell    outlets are wrong)
- Sometimes objective c doesn't set properties with dot syntax. try `[cell.myImageView setImage:]`method.
- Check is your imageview visible. Autolayout can resize it to 0 if you have constraint conflicts.

**Afnetworking process:**
Download from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
You will only use UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h-.m files but it has referances from main afnetworking folder. Check referances and add what you need.

Import UIImageView+AFNetworking.m to the class which you set cell's image.

Then you can use like:

```
[cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:(NSURL*) placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"R1.jpg"]];
```

Comment: Your answer is little more than a link only AND it does nothing to dealing with the OPs problem. Try slowing down, reading the question and providing a complete useful answer IF you in fact have one. it's OK to not answer questions.

Comment: Ok. ty for information. But if he checks his resource file as i wrote static image will be visible then if he adds afnetworking, lazyloading will be ok too. Should i explain how afnetworking should implements here? I didnt saw any other problem so i suggest my bests. (maybe local image can be about uiimageviews outlets too but that is so obviuous)

Comment: Consider reasons why the static image isn't loading , there's several . Or maybe it is loading and isn't visible , again a couple of possibilities. How do you use AFNetworking functionality here, maybe a code snippet.  How is the OP even loading his/her remote image in the first place. Find out. All these things go into a good answer.

Answer (score -2):

There are some cool libraries solving your problem.

One of them is [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/tree/master/SDWebImage).

Just add it to your Project and import UIImageView+WebCache.h in your implementation file of your tableviewcontroller.

Create an array of URLs in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or init and load them into your cells in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method by calling

```
[cell.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[arrImageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
```

[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2image] to get the URLs

Comment: i am using storyboard and autolayout. Will that create any conflict ?

Comment: How does this solve his problem? He doesn't have a URL image, he has a static one thats in his project...

Comment: Well, the question does say "Sometimes downloading takes time, if so how do i implement lazyloading, so it'll download and display images simultaneously". But of course that is a totally different question and shouldn't be grouped together like this.

Comment: He gets the URL with [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2image]